# Interacting with web pages in C#

Tags: c#, automation, screen-scraping, html-parsing

There is a website that was created using ColdFusion (not sure if this matters or not). I need to interact with this web site. The main things I need to do are navigate to different pages and click buttons.

I have come up with two ideas on how to do this. The first is to use the WebBrowser control. With this, I could certainly navigate pages, and click buttons (According to [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/20474a99-3e11-44ec-815c-614a8d3f4b43)).

The other way is to interact with the html directly. Not sure exactly how to do this, but I am assuming I could click buttons or use HTML requests to interact with the page.

Does anyone have a recommendation on which way is better? Is there a better way that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Try [WatiN](http://watin.org/).

Comment: As others have posted below, the normal way to scape a site in .NET is to use a HttpWebRequest.  You can easily navigate a site using code and issue post/get requests to simulate interactions (button pushes).  You should record the process using Fiddler (FREE proxy), which will allow you to see the entire process of how you interact with the website, so you can re-create it in code.  The HtmlAgilityPack is a great tool for parsing HTML, which may be needed depending on what you are scraping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use [Html AgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the html and then do POSTs and GETs appropriately with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

While it may be possible to use the WebBrowser control to simulate clicks and navigation you get more control with Html AgilityPack and HttpWebRequest regarding what gets sent

Answer (score 5):

Did you consider [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)? The [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-webdriver) API is quite good, and permits a lot of things in terms of Website automation.

Comment: broken link here

Answer (score 2):

[HtmlAguilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is useful for pulling the web elements and finding tags easily. If you need to remotely "steer" a web session, though, I prefer to use [WatiN](https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/). It bills itself as a web unit testing framework, but it's very useful anytime you need to fake a browser section. Further, it can remote control different browsers well enough for most tasks you'll need (like finding a button and pushing it, or a text field and filling in text if you need a login).

Comment: WatiN is a dead link.  Takes you elsewhere and no guarantee of hijacking your session.  :o

Answer (score 2):

why not submit directly the url? that's what the button click will do. 
using [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx) you can submit directly to the url. no need to load, parse and "click" the button.